# Как правильно объявлять bean в приложении написанном на spring?

Tags: java, spring, архитектура, spring-boot

Пишу приложение на spring-boot, вопрос связан с правильным проектированием приложения на spring с точки зрения архитектуры, не совсем понимаю какие классы объявлять @Bean а какие нет необходимости, или все классы в приложении spring должны быть объявлены как @Bean.
Например у меня есть класс NewTokenSession.java

```
    package famaly.people.auth.token.worker;

    import famaly.people.auth.obj.Token;

    public class NewTokenSession implements TokenWorker {

    private Token token;

    @Override
    public void generate(Token token){

    }
    @Override
    public Token getNewTokenToSession() {
        return token;
    }
   }
```

И он объявлен как @Bean. Я использую его в единичном экземпляре.
У меня есть еще класс Session.java

```
package famaly.people.auth.session;

import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Session implements UserSession{
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateCreateSession;
    protected String sessionName;
    protected  boolean isValidSession;

    public Session(String sessionName, XMLGregorianCalendar dateCreateSession, boolean isValidSession) {
        this.sessionName = sessionName;
        this.dateCreateSession = dateCreateSession;
        this.isValidSession = isValidSession;
    }

    public String getSessionName(){
        return sessionName;
    }

    public  XMLGregorianCalendar getDateCreateSession(){
        return dateCreateSession;
    }

    public boolean isValidSession() {
        return isValidSession;
    }
}
```

И каждый раз генерируется новый экземпляр этого класса + в конструкторе используются параметры и каждый экземпляр этого класса я добавлю в  HashSet<,>.
Нужно ли мне и его объявлять @Bean или необязательно, или при написании приложения на spring нужно обязательно объявлять такие классы @Bean, чтобы ими управлял контейнер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме @Bean существует еще масса других полезных аннотаций: @Repository @Service @Controller @Entity... они все помогают делать код менее связанным.

Вместо жесткой связки YourClassName var = new...; т.е. четкого указания, что, вот именно этот класс, именно этот и никакой другой. Вы можете использовать всю мощь Dependency Injection и Spring сам будет находить нужные классы (отмеченные аннотациями) и делать их объекты бинами. В результате, Вы легко сможете развивать ваше приложение, использовать более универсальный код (на основе интерфейсов), подменять, когда нужно, одни классы другими и т.д.

Но у концепции бинов есть и еще одна плюшка. Например важным свойством бина является то, что это Singltone (объект создаваемый только в одном экземпляре). А это очень важно. Например (гипотетическая ситуация) на сервер одновременно запрыгивает 100_000 пользователей или даже больше... ага и все классы вашего приложения начинает дружно генерировать по 100_000 экземпляров. Ведь каждый раз вы пишите new... А это совсем не приятно. Память быстро заполняется, включается сборщик мусора, ваш сервер начинает тормозить ведь уборка - это совсем не бесплатно. Конечно, вы можете в ручную проделать всю работу по созданию и обработке очередей, самим объявлять синглтоны и т.д. ... Но, представьте, для вас это уже все сделано в Spring.

Надеюсь эта информация поможет вам понять силу используемых вами технологий и самим далее ответить на архитектурные вопросы.

Comment: Просто я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у меня есть класс родитель, а класс юзер наследует из этого класса. И я при инициализации в конструкторе задаю значения полям и дочернего класса и класса родителя, и я не понимаю как я могу задать им поля? С помощью отдельного метода, а когда структур без параметром, или другим способом?

Comment: т.е. нужно ли объявлять бином родителя? В этом нет никакой необходимости. Если вы используете объект наследника (как бин), то предок уже включен в его состав. public class Dog extends Animal{
    Dog(){
        age = 10;
    }
}

Comment: Вопрос еще связан с тем, например:
У меня есть класс class Animal{ protected string color}
и класс class Dog extends animal {private string name;}
как при инициализации(создания) бина, мне задать для родительского класса Animal значение в поле color(например), раньше я через конструктор передавал значение super(...), теперь нужно использовать отдельную функцию для инициальзации, например void setProperties(String color){this.color= color} в родительском классе или есть другие боле правильные, с точки зрения архитектуры, варианты?

Comment: Через сеттер (вы это назвали отдельной функцией для инициализации) вполне норм вариант.